# Repeated rosmake failure

Tags: ros, rosmake, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install ardrone_autonomy and tum_ardrone, both of which I have downloaded. However, whenever I use rosmake with these packages I get the error

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/hydro/ardrone_autonomy/build/catkin_generated/generate_cached_setup.py")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:178 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  /opt/ros/hydro/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:249 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

It's consistently the same error for both packages. Any ideas as to what is causing this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/147906/repeated-rosmake-failure/) by [ahadik](https://answers.ros.org/users/14251/ahadik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not use rosmake with catkin packages, but rather catkin_make. I advise to read up on catkin in the wiki if you have not used it before: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0